# Find Continuous curves from arbitrary data using python

Tags: python, sorting, plot, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I have this given set of data:

```
snew = [0.0, 0.643, 0.173, -0.499, -0.939, -0.939, -0.866, -0.984, -0.642, 0.0]
cnew = [1.0, 0.766, 0.984, 0.866, 0.342, -0.342, -0.866, 0.173, 0.766, 1.0]
```

and when I plot them I get something like this -

[image: unsorted raw data]

```
data = np.vstack((snew, cnew)).T
x_point = np.linspace(0,9,10)

plt.figure()
plt.title('given data')
plt.plot(x_point, data, marker = 'o')
```

But I want something like this -

[image: expected sorted data]

How can I obtain this using python?

Comment: The curves you expect look like cosine and sine; you can get them as `t = np.arange(10); x = np.cos(t); y = np.sin(t)`

Comment: Yes, I took a sample dataset that does look like sine and cosine, but I am looking for something more general which can handle more than 2 curves of arbitrary shape.